# How to query this html element?

Tags: html, dom

[A different DOM element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjxBD.jpg)

I was checking source code of youtube and found I couldn't query these elements from DOM. what are these ?

I was expecting the element to be queryable using javascript.

**Update I found the answer**it is a web component and can be queried as a shadow root. What problem does web component solve ?

**source** - https://kevinsimper.medium.com/document-queryselector-with-web-components-76a8be5bc59

Comment: It’s not at all clear what the actual question is here anymore. Please limit posts to a single inquiry only; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

These are custom tags that you wouldn't find in most code bases.

However, fret not. You can still query this elements with the following selector:

```
let thumbnailArray = document.querySelectorAll("#dismissible > ytd-thumbnail");
```

If you want to query an element, but can't figure out a selector that returns something, you can always right click on the element and mouse over the copy option, then "copy selector".

[image]

Here is the list of thumbnails returned into the array:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is the react element of youtube. That's why we cannot query it from anywhere. We can create own element in react. These are one of those.

***** THANKS *****

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).